# Providing full path to java in gitlab config

Tags: java, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

In my gitlab-ci.yml configuration I have the following snippet:

```
  before_script:
    - java -jar /home/gitlab-runner/tools/ciVersioner-1.0.jar $MAJOR $MINOR $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
  script:
    - mvn --projects employees --also-make clean package -DskipTests
  after_script:
    - echo $HOSTNAME $WHOAMI
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - employees/target/*.jar
    expire_in: 30 days
```

It does not work but for a different reason (since java versions are incompatible).
Here's the output:

[image]

The solution was to install a newer java 11.

I did so and changed the configuration correspondingly:

```
  before_script:
    - /opt/java11/jdk-11/bin/java -jar /home/gitlab-runner/tools/ciVersioner-1.0.jar $MAJOR $MINOR $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
  script:
    - mvn --projects employees --also-make clean package -DskipTests
  after_script:
    - echo $HOSTNAME $WHOAMI
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - employees/target/*.jar
    expire_in: 30 days
```

However, with this configuration nothing works at all:
[image]

But if I execute this command in VM environment directly, it works as expected.

Is there a limitation on using full qualified path in the yml file or maybe it has to do with something else?

Answer (score 0):

Before you updated java the job fail at the java command, so it didn't try to execute mvn.

However, when the first problem is solved, you get a new issue and now with mvn command.

I guess the runner cannot recognize mvn because maven is not installed.
You could try adding the following to the before_script section:

```
- apt-get update && apt-get install maven
```

This is will depend on the linux distribution, use yum instead if the runner is on redhat or centos